# Decompile android apk file to create java source code

Tags: android

I have use of 3 tools as 1)apktool 1.5.2.tar.bz2
2)dex2jar-0.0.9.13.zip
3)jd-gui-0.3.5.windows.zip

But i got following error on cmd when i use command on cmd as:  C:\New folder\Tea.apk>dex2jar classes.dex

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM`could not reserve enough space for object heap code Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I made change vm heap size 500 MB in control panel but the  same error occurred as above.
please ,send the solution to given problem .Thanks in advance

Comment: "send the solution to given problem" -- license the source code from the author of the app.